# AngularJS migration to webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, migration, ecmascript-5

My case is that we have application with stack: AngularJS and ES5 and we want to use webpack. Migration of all of the .js files (rewrite it to ES6 Classes etc.) is a big problem because of the size of the project. Is there any way to migrate it to webpack without making full refactor? The situation that we use webpack with new modules and the other modules are only plugged to webpack (somehow) with old dependency injection etc. would be satisfactory. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: You could perhaps use commonjs to require all your old files in your root app module file and then set that file as your webpack entry point, but I highly suggest, if you're going this route anyway, that you work towards migrating to ES6 classes. You should be able to do it gradually.